# Android native activity, GLES 3.0 shader compilations fails

Tags: android, c++, opengl-es, android-ndk

I wanted to experiment with Native Activity and GLES 3.0, for a personal project, until I hit this roadblock: The shaders won't load and/or compile, I'm not really sure, as OPENGL's logs are non-existent.

Here are both of my shaders:

```
static const char glVertexShader[] =
"#version 300 es\n"
"in vec4 vPosition;\n"
"void main()\n"
"{\n"
"  gl_Position = vPosition;\n"
"}\n\0";

static const char glFragmentShader[] =
"#version 300 es\n"
"precision mediump float;\n"
"void main()\n"
"{\n"
"  gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);\n"
"}\n\0";
```

And here are my shader loading and program creation functions:

```
GLuint loadShader(GLenum shaderType, const char* shaderSource)
{
    GLuint shader = glCreateShader(shaderType);
    if (shader)
    {
        glShaderSource(shader, 1, &shaderSource, NULL);
        glCompileShader(shader);
        GLint compiled = 0;
        glGetShaderiv(shader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &compiled);
        if (!compiled)
        {
            GLint infoLen = 0;
            glGetShaderiv(shader, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &infoLen);
            if (infoLen)
            {
                char * buf = new char[infoLen];
                if (buf)
                {
                    glGetShaderInfoLog(shader, infoLen, NULL, buf);
                    log.log_error("Could not Compile Shader %d:\n%s\n", shaderType, buf);
                    delete[] buf;
                }
                glDeleteShader(shader);
                shader = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    return shader;
}

GLuint createProgram(const char* vertexSource, const char * fragmentSource)
{
    log.log_info("Loading vertex shader");
    GLuint vertexShader = loadShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER, vertexSource);
    if (!vertexShader)
    {
        log.log_info("Vertex shader load failure!");
        return 0;
    }
    log.log_info("Loading fragment shader");
    GLuint fragmentShader = loadShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, fragmentSource);
    if (!fragmentShader)
    {
        log.log_info("Fragment shader load failure!");
        return 0;
    }
    GLuint program = glCreateProgram();

    if (program)
    {
        glAttachShader(program, vertexShader);
        glAttachShader(program, fragmentShader);
        glLinkProgram(program);
        GLint linkStatus = GL_FALSE;
        glGetProgramiv(program, GL_LINK_STATUS, &linkStatus);

        if (linkStatus != GL_TRUE)
        {
            GLint bufLength = 0;
            glGetProgramiv(program, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &bufLength);
            if (bufLength)
            {
                char* buf = new char[bufLength];
                if (buf)
                {
                    glGetProgramInfoLog(program, bufLength, NULL, buf);
                    log.log_error("Could not link program:\n%s\n", buf);
                    delete[] buf;
                }
            }
            glDeleteProgram(program);
            program = 0;
        }
    }
    return program;
}
```

I'll also include my setup code and drawing code below:

Setup code:

```
GLuint simpleTriangleProgram;
GLuint vPosition;
bool setupGraphics(int w, int h)
{
    simpleTriangleProgram = createProgram(glVertexShader, glFragmentShader);
    if (!simpleTriangleProgram)
    {
        log.log_error("Could not create program");
        return false;
    }
    vPosition = glGetAttribLocation(simpleTriangleProgram, "vPosition");
    glViewport(0, 0, w, h);
    return true;
}
```

Drawing code:

```
//-------------------------------
const GLfloat triangleVertices[] = {
    0.0f, 1.0f,
    -1.0f, -1.0f,
    1.0f, -1.0f
};
//-------------------------------


/**
* Just the current frame in the display.
*/
static void engine_draw_frame(struct engine* engine) {
    if (engine->display == NULL) {
        // No display.
        return;
    }

    // Just fill the screen with a color.
    glClearColor(((float)engine->state.x) / engine->width, engine->state.angle,
        ((float)engine->state.y) / engine->height, 1);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    //---------------------------------------------------
    glUseProgram(simpleTriangleProgram);
    glVertexAttribPointer(vPosition, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, triangleVertices);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(vPosition);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
    //---------------------------------------------------

    eglSwapBuffers(engine->display, engine->surface);
}
```

And yes, the GLES context is properly created. <strike>But let me know if I should post that code too.</strike>

Here's my context creation code:

```
/**
* Initialize an EGL context for the current display.
*/
static int engine_init_display(struct engine* engine) {
    // initialize OpenGL ES and EGL

    /*
    * Here specify the attributes of the desired configuration.
    * Below, we select an EGLConfig with at least 8 bits per color
    * component compatible with on-screen windows
    */
    const EGLint attribs[] = {
        EGL_RENDERABLE_TYPE, EGL_OPENGL_ES2_BIT,
        EGL_SURFACE_TYPE, EGL_WINDOW_BIT,
        EGL_BLUE_SIZE, 8,
        EGL_GREEN_SIZE, 8,
        EGL_RED_SIZE, 8,
        EGL_NONE
    };
    EGLint w, h, format;
    EGLint numConfigs;
    EGLConfig config;
    EGLSurface surface;
    EGLContext context;

    EGLDisplay display = eglGetDisplay(EGL_DEFAULT_DISPLAY);

    eglInitialize(display, 0, 0);

    /* Here, the application chooses the configuration it desires.
    * find the best match if possible, otherwise use the very first one
    */
    eglChooseConfig(display, attribs, NULL, 0, &numConfigs);
    std::unique_ptr<EGLConfig[]> supportedConfigs(new EGLConfig[numConfigs]);
    assert(supportedConfigs);
    eglChooseConfig(display, attribs, supportedConfigs.get(), numConfigs, &numConfigs);
    assert(numConfigs);
    auto i = 0;
    for (; i < numConfigs; i++) {
        auto& cfg = supportedConfigs[i];
        EGLint r, g, b, d;
        if (eglGetConfigAttrib(display, cfg, EGL_RED_SIZE, &r) &&
            eglGetConfigAttrib(display, cfg, EGL_GREEN_SIZE, &g) &&
            eglGetConfigAttrib(display, cfg, EGL_BLUE_SIZE, &b) &&
            eglGetConfigAttrib(display, cfg, EGL_DEPTH_SIZE, &d) &&
            r == 8 && g == 8 && b == 8 && d == 0) {

            config = supportedConfigs[i];
            break;
        }
    }
    if (i == numConfigs) {
        config = supportedConfigs[0];
    }

    EGLint AttribList[] =
    {
        EGL_CONTEXT_CLIENT_VERSION, 3,
        EGL_NONE
    };

    /* EGL_NATIVE_VISUAL_ID is an attribute of the EGLConfig that is
    * guaranteed to be accepted by ANativeWindow_setBuffersGeometry().
    * As soon as we picked a EGLConfig, we can safely reconfigure the
    * ANativeWindow buffers to match, using EGL_NATIVE_VISUAL_ID. */
    eglGetConfigAttrib(display, config, EGL_NATIVE_VISUAL_ID, &format);
    surface = eglCreateWindowSurface(display, config, engine->app->window, NULL);
    context = eglCreateContext(display, config, NULL, AttribList);

    if (eglMakeCurrent(display, surface, surface, context) == EGL_FALSE) {
        log.log_warning("Unable to eglMakeCurrent");
        return -1;
    }

    eglQuerySurface(display, surface, EGL_WIDTH, &w);
    eglQuerySurface(display, surface, EGL_HEIGHT, &h);

    engine->display = display;
    engine->context = context;
    engine->surface = surface;
    engine->width = w;
    engine->height = h;
    engine->state.angle = 0;

    // Check openGL on the system
    auto opengl_info = { GL_VENDOR, GL_RENDERER, GL_VERSION, GL_EXTENSIONS };
    for (auto name : opengl_info) {
        auto info = glGetString(name);
        log.log_info("OpenGL Info: %s", info);
    }
    // Initialize GL state.
    // glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
    // glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

    return 0;
}
```

Full log:
[Log pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z4O8m.png)

Note: my logger class is just a wrapper for `__android_log_vprint()`. I didn't include it because it isn't relevant in the slightest.

Comment: Yes, no null pointers nor anything. Everything works fine, except that the shaders don't compile/link, not entirely sure, since OpenGL isn't giving me any logs.

Comment: Which bit fails? Is it that 'compiled' is false?

Comment: From my own code.... "Vertex shader load failure", then it returns. But is the same for the fragment shader. Because of this, I get "Could not create program" right after.

Comment: So you're not getting the "Could not Compile Shader" logging before the "Vertex shader load failure!" logging? The only way that's happening is if glCreateShader is returning 0. Pretty much the only way that's happening is when the GLES context is not properly created and set as the context for the current thread.

Comment: @Columbo I've updated my question with my context creation code and a log (I'm currently away from my development PC, so all I could do was take a log straight from my phone).

Comment: OK - that log tells me that glCreateShader is returning 0. Look at your context - assuming it's created successfully, perhaps it isn't bound to the thread that's trying to load the shader. (either that or 'new char[infoLen]' is returning 0, but that seems incredibly unlikely).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the log posted, glCreateShader is returning 0 which only happens when the context is not valid.

Looking at the time stamps in the log, you appear to be loading your shaders before you are creating the OpenGLES context.

Comment: Whoa. I wasn't aware of that. You are not supposed to init your context on `void android_main(struct android_app* state)`, but rather, on `void engine_handle_cmd(struct android_app* app, int32_t cmd)`, more specifically, when `cmd == APP_CMD_INIT_WINDOW`.

That is, context initialization has to happen every time, not just once, in `main()`. That's a bit different from what I'm used to, but it explains why it worked under Windows, and not on Android.

Answer (score 2):

This:

```
#version 300 es
attribute vec4 vPosition;
void main()
{
  gl_Position = vPosition;
}
```

... isn't a legal ESSL version 300 shader, so you should be getting a compile error log returned by the compiler on your platform. Do you not get anything from your log_info log channel?

To make the shader legal replace `attribute` with `in`.

Comment: I updated my question with `attribute` replaced by `in`, but there's still nothing being rendered